# Matrices inequality $xt(A+B )x<0$, if $xtBx >0$ can we conclude $xtAx<0$

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

If matrix $B$ is positive definite, $xtBx >0$ and we have that $(A+B)$ is negative definite, $xt(A+B)x <0,$

Can we prove that $xtAx <0$ ($A$ is negative definite)? How? Everywhere used x just to show definiteness property is there...

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2):

If $B$ is positive definite then $$\langle Bx,x\rangle >0.$$

If $A+B$ is negative definite then $$\langle (A+B)x,x\rangle <0.$$

Thus

$$\langle Ax,x\rangle+\langle Bx,x\rangle<0,$$ from where

$$\langle Ax,x\rangle<-\langle Bx,x\rangle<0.$$ That is, $A$ is negative definite.